# How to Button a Rules Link URL

Tags: rules, theming, navigation

I'm using Rules Link, via a Views block set in a user Panel page. At the moment it sits ready for a users click response to trigger an event and works fine in its approach.

Prior to major Theming/CSS, I would like to have the generic 'Blue' URL text link show as a graphic button (ie generic 'bootstrap' style), can anyone advise the quickest way to change this so I can get a feel of the layout and look. I presume it's a CSS template addition, can someone give me some tips (I'm using Bootstrap)
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After study, I used the above css with a 'btn btn-primary btn-block' in the Other of my View (where the Rule itself goes) in the CSS information properties.  It for now gave me a working button, but it does need some further CSS, but I have my answer.

Additionally, I added :

```
/* Rules Link Post unvisited link */
.rules-link-post-classified
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

into my theme.css (using currently the Tweme Bootstrap).
As I wanted white text on a blue button, and then I used the above css with a 'btn btn-primary btn-block' in the other of my View in the CSS information properties.

Furthermore, I didn't want the 'hover' underline to show on the link when the user moved over it to click, so I used the text-decoration as 'none' to remove it under the 'a:hover' with 'a:active' elements above.
BINGO!

There maybe more functional CSS ways in the file.css, but hey we're learning!

Comment: Alternatively, "btn btn-info btn-block" for a wide button (-: